# receiving error 3075: syntax error for combo box linked to text box

Tags: vba, ms-access

I keep getting this error whenever I try to run my form,

[image: screenshot of form]

And the error:

[image: error]

The idea of this is to choose a field, enter in the text and have it pull the records base on the text input and it will say "no records found" if there is no match. Still a VBA novice, any help would be appreciated. The code is below. *cboField* is the combobox and *txtBox* is the textbox. I'm running  Access 2010 for reference.

```
Option Compare Database

Private Sub cboField_Enter()

   Dim oRS As DAO.Recordset, i As Integer
   If Me.Form.FilterOn = True Then DoCmd.ShowAllRecords

   Set oRS = Me.RecordsetClone

   cboField.RowSourceType = "Value List"
   cboField.RowSource = ""

   For i = 0 To oRS.Fields.Count - 1
      If oRS.Fields(i).Type = dbText Then cboField.AddItem oRS.Fields(i).Name
   Next i

End Sub

Private Sub txtBox_Exit(Cancel As Integer)

   Dim sfilter As String, oRS As DAO.Recordset
   If IsNull(cboField) Then
      DoCmd.ShowAllRecords
      MsgBox "select a field"
      Exit Sub
   End If

   If IsNull(txtBox) Then DoCmd.ShowAllRecords: Exit Sub

   sfilter = cboField & "LIKE '" & txtBox & " *'"
   DoCmd.ApplyFilter , sfilter

   Set oRS = Me.RecordsetClone

   If oRS.RecordCount = 0 Then
      MsgBox " no record matches"
      DoCmd.ShowAllRecords
   End If

End Sub
```

Comment: whenever I run debug it highlights docmd.applyfilter, sfitler. Are there extra parameters needed here maybe ?

Comment: Try adding a space before `"LIKE '"`

Comment: ^^ "Do... or do not. There is no try" - and in this case ... "Do".  The missing space will be causing that message - look at the message closely and try to find the operator in the three tokens `FirstNameLIKE`, `joe` and `*`.

Comment: I added the space before, and that fixed the error, however, now when i select a field and enter in a name, and click outside of the textbox, it returns my "no records found message" when I enter joe for the firstname. is the wildcard place awkwardly in the filter statement ? here is a capture of the entered data against the vba : sfilter = "FirstName LIKE 'joe *'".

Comment: Probably shouldn't have the space in front of *.

Comment: ^^ "Have or don't have. There is no probably" - and in this case... "Don't have". Yoda could have said that.

Answer (score 0):

*... Avoid answering questions in comments.*

Anyway. When building SQL strings in VBA, `Debug.Print` and reading the output closely are your friends. [How to debug dynamic SQL in VBA](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1099570/3820271)

```
Debug.Print sfilter
```

```
FirstNameLIKE 'joe *'
```

Watch for missing and superfluous spaces, make that

```
sfilter = cboField & " LIKE '" & txtBox & "*'"
```

Comment: Questions are answered in comments because: 1. Answerer is not sure if they have a correct answer, 2. Answerer is not interested in being downvoted for posting an answer that someone doesn't like. I do it all the time,

Answer (score 0):

It is working now, thanks to all for the help, I have posted the source with the edits.

```
Option Compare Database

Private Sub cboField_Enter()
Dim oRS As DAO.Recordset, i As Integer
If Me.Form.FilterOn = True Then DoCmd.ShowAllRecords
Set oRS = Me.RecordsetClone
cboField.RowSourceType = "Value List"
cboField.RowSource = ""

For i = 0 To oRS.Fields.Count - 1
If oRS.Fields(i).Type = dbText Then cboField.AddItem oRS.Fields(i).Name
 Next i

 End Sub

 Private Sub txtBox_Exit(Cancel As Integer)
 Dim sfilter As String, oRS As DAO.Recordset
 If IsNull(cboField) Then
 DoCmd.ShowAllRecords
 MsgBox "select a field"
 Exit Sub
 End If
 If IsNull(txtBox) Then DoCmd.ShowAllRecords: Exit Sub
 sfilter = cboField & " LIKE '" & txtBox & "*'"
 DoCmd.ApplyFilter , sfilter
 Debug.Print sfilter


 Set oRS = Me.RecordsetClone
 If oRS.RecordCount = 0 Then
 MsgBox " no record matches"
 DoCmd.ShowAllRecords
 End If

 End Sub
```